# Permission route on static file express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to authenticate user when he request some page that has static route.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/app');
```

Assume that the folder "templates" is under the path above ('/public/app/templates') :

```
app.get('/templates/permissionPage.html',function(req,res){
// if user is authorized.. reutrn the page,
else return 401..
});
```

my routing even don't enter the get request of the page. how can I handle that request? 
I want that only specific users can access this page, although he got static route.

I am using angularJS on my front-end

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Easy one: auth users on your web-server (proxy-server). Docs for [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html), and for [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)
2. Hard one: Build accounts and auth module for your app. This will require work with storage (database), logic, and UI/UX.  Or use ready solutions, like [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate)